# Why do we need $scope.apply() when do a change from console but not otherwise?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Say there is an AngularJS controller like this:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.controller('TimeCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  var tick = function() {
    $scope.clock = Date.now();
    window.scope = $scope;
  }
  tick();
  $interval(tick, 1000);
});
```

1. Changing `$scope.clock` would automatically reflect in the DOM.
   However, when I do it in the console, I need to do explicitly do
   `$scope.apply`. Why is it so? Is `$interval` doing some magic?
2. In general, don't I need to `$scope.watch` these variables? I thought the purpose of `$scope.watch` was this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
$interval(f, time)
```

is more or less

```
setInterval(function() {
   f();
   $rootScope.$apply();
}, time)
```

2.

`<div>{{test}}</div>`

is more or less

```
$scope.$watch('test', function(value) {
  divElement.innerHTML = value;
})
```

Comment: Nice. Very quick and precise. Every `{{variable}}`  becomes watched?  For example `ng-show={{variable}}`. I think it can become complex if it is an expression though.

Comment: you can always look at angular source https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/03043839d5a540b02208001fe12e812dfde00a8e/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js

{{}} is processed in similar way.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it so? Is `$interval` doing some magic?

Yes, it is. It is triggering automatically the [AngularJS digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest), something you do "manually" with the `$scope.$apply()` (which also triggers it). This causes the changes to be reflected in the DOM. If the digest cycle is not triggered, AngularJS "does not know changes have been made in the model, so it does not update the DOM".

> (...) don't I need to watch these variables?

No, unless you need to be notified when any of these variables have changed their values. As long as you do all changes inside the AngularJS scope the DOM will always be "notified" (updated).

How to know when I am doing the thing inside the AngularJS scope?

Usually when you use functions provided by services such as [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) and [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), you're doing things inside the scope, because these are wrappers of the original ([`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)) and trigger automatically the mentioned digest cycle, keeping things synced between model and DOM.

So, **finally**,

> Why do we need `$scope.apply()` when doing a change from console but not
>   otherwise?

Because from console you are doing some changes outside the AngularJS scope and need to trigger the mentioned digest cycle by yourself.